# Can paramagnetics materials like iron be levitated by a spinning halbech array like aluminium, copper etc?

Tags: magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

I know diamagnetic conductors like aluminium or copper can be levitated using a spinning Halbech array as in [this video](https://fb.watch/89VGc8cEQG/). But can the same work using paramagmetic conductors, specifically iron?

Or will the paramagnetism always overwhelm the diamagnetic effect?

Also what influences the strength of the repulsion? The speed of spinning (ie the rate of alternation of the current? The strength of the magnets?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Update - The repulsion definitely increases with faster spinning as wikipedia says:

> Faraday's law states that the EMF is also given by the rate of change
> of the magnetic flux where epsilon is the electromotive force (EMF)
> and $\phi_B$ is the magnetic flux.

$$\varepsilon = - \frac{-d \phi_B}{dt}$$
I think repulsion will also be greater with stronger magnets.

In testing going to about 5-10000 RPM with 8 8x8x8 neodymium magnets doesnt seem to be able to repel iron. Perhaps faster reciprocation might though beyond my capabilities.